# wmtsa package, summary method for same functions

Tags: r, package

Another stupid question.

I use "wmtsa" package for MODWT/MODWPT. So, let's look simple code:

```
t <- 1:100;
a1 <- 0;
b1 <- 0;

dataVector <- a*sin(2*pi*t/length(t)) + b1 + rt(length(t), df = 3, ncp = 0);

maxDecompositionLvl <- ilogb(length(dataVector), base=2);
transformedData <- wavMODWT(dataVector, keep.series=FALSE, wavelet="d4"); 

waveletVariance <- summary(transformedData);
waveletVariance
```

I've got an output:

```
> waveletVariance

      Min     1Q Median    3Q   Max   Mean    SD   Var   MAD Energy %
d1 -3.635 -0.685  0.025 0.635 3.639  0.000 1.135 1.289 1.012   44.540
d2 -2.493 -0.489  0.064 0.546 2.395  0.000 0.859 0.738 0.719   25.499
d3 -1.402 -0.304  0.085 0.365 1.239  0.000 0.554 0.307 0.533   10.594
d4 -1.121 -0.249  0.040 0.292 1.055  0.000 0.478 0.228 0.388    7.892
d5 -0.859 -0.395  0.102 0.407 0.610  0.000 0.443 0.196 0.522    6.768
d6 -0.490 -0.220 -0.042 0.271 0.541  0.000 0.323 0.104 0.372    3.602
s6 -0.304 -0.236 -0.131 0.043 0.131 -0.105 0.145 0.021 0.177    1.105

Energy Distribution:
           1st     1%     2%     3%     4%     5%    10%     15%     20%
Energy % 4.622 21.672 30.489 37.131 42.913 47.424 62.668  72.107  78.768
|coeffs| 3.639  2.395  1.734  1.588  1.456  1.314  0.964   0.806   0.674
#coeffs  1.000  7.000 14.000 21.000 28.000 35.000 70.000 105.000 140.000
             25%
Energy %  83.400
|coeffs|   0.563
#coeffs  175.000
```

So, I strongly need to understand how summary method calculates `Energy %`, `Energy Distribution` and same other values. How it possible to look? r-forge isn't a variant, because r-forge code so old and have not enough .R files to answer my question.

Thank you.

Comment: See the end of `wmtsa:::summary.wavTransform`.

Comment: Oh, great! Thank you much again!! You are the best!))